# SQL Server get value from a xml file in internet site

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

There is a xml file in www.samplexxxxx.com/myfile.xml

I want to read or query this file with SQL Server in my computer

Can I make this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? This is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example: http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/11/import-xml-file-to-sql-table.html

Also see [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/read-xml-file-in-sql-server-2008) for another option

Quite a bit of manual work. It's a bit of a square peg in a round hole, DBMS systems aren't great at working with XML data. I would recommend parsing the XML using Java, PHP, python, whatever...and inserting the data into a DBMS if needed.